# Azure Dev OPs Pipeline Variable is not being evaluated

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, cicd

I want to check if my pipeline is running on a branch called releases.
This would then enable/disable stages for the pipeline.

```
variables:
  isReleaseBranch: $[contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/')]
```

It would be a lot cleaner if I could get the variable to fix. I've spent more than a day on this, I'm sure I'm either doing something silly or missing something.

This is one of the if statements I've tried

```
- ${{ if variables.isReleaseBranch }}
  - stage: DoSomething
```

I've also tried

```
- ${{ if variables['isReleaseBranch'] }}
  - stage: DoSomething
```

Even tried

```
- ${{ if eq(variables['isReleaseBranch'], true) }}
  - stage: DoSomething
```

Only when I put the condition in if statment I get something which works.

```
- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases/') }}:
  - stage: DoSomething
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `/` at the end of value `$(Build.SourceBranch)`, it should be `refs/heads/releases`.

Sample as below:

```
stages:
- stage: DoSomething
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases')
  jobs:
  - job: Job1
    steps: 
      - script: echo $(Build.SourceBranch)
```

If you would like to use if expression, you need to make sure at least one stage has no dependencies.

```
stages:
- stage: stage1
  jobs:
  - job: job1
    steps:
    - script: echo Building the app...

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/releases') }}: # if expression to check the branch name
  - stage: DoSomething
    jobs:
      - job: Job1
        steps: 
        - script: echo $(Build.SourceBranch)
```

Comment: I simply wanted to do something like: -${{ if variable.isReleaseBranch }} in place of the variables['Build.SourceBranch'] check as it would be cleaner.

Comment: The new variable defined in pipeline cannot be used in if expression for your scenario, only predefined variable is supported(as my sample above). This is because if expression will evaluate on compile time, but new variable is evaluated at runtime.

Comment: This is a yaml sample for if expression with variable([Conditionally run a step](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/expressions?view=azure-devops#conditionally-run-a-step)), it's working because the variable value is **hardcoded** . For your variable `isReleaseBranch`, the value is not hardcode or predefined. cannot be used in if expression.

Comment: Ah okay, right, so only the variables['Build.SourceBranch'] would work. Ty

Comment: Glad to know it helps! In order to let others who have the similar question with you know how you resolved it more clearly, could you please help to [mark it as answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235) according to How does accepting an answer work. Thanks and wish you a good day ahead!

Answer (score 0):

1. you should remove the last **'/'** from **'refs/heads/releases/'**. if using contains expression, which will render to false.
2. I have tried your case and test some additional more cases.

---

below is my test, and my branch called master and yours is main, it does not matter.

```
variables:
  isReleaseBranch: $[contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
  isReleaseBranch1: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')]
  var1: test

steps:
- ${{ if eq(variables.var1, 'test')}}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "running test00 in $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    name: test00

- ${{ if eq(variables.isReleaseBranch, true )}}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "running test01 in $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    name: test01

- ${{ if eq(variables.isReleaseBranch1, true )}}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "running test001 in $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    name: test001

- ${{ if contains(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "running test1 in $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    name: test1

- ${{ if eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master') }}:
  - powershell: |
      Write-Host "running test2 in $(Build.SourceBranch)"
    name: test2

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "running test3 in $(Build.SourceBranch)"
  name: test3
  condition: eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/master')
```

[image]

**test01** and **test02** can't be rendered. I think it may be the reason of **"runtime"** and **"compile-time"**, expression render is be in the process of compile, but **"isReleaseBranch"** and **"isReleaseBranch1"** refer to a runtime variables, so can't be evaluated. It just my opinion not sure to be correct.